# Kafka consumer using AWS_MSK_IAM ClassCastException error

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk, aws-databricks, aws-iam-authenticator

I have MSK running on AWS and I'd like to consume information using AWS_MSK_IAM authentication.

My MSK is properly configured and I can consume the information using Kafka CLI with the following command:

```
../bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server b-1.kafka.*********.***********.amazonaws.com:9098 --consumer.config client_auth.properties --topic TopicTest --from-beginning
```

My client_auth.properties has the following information:

```
# Sets up TLS for encryption and SASL for authN.
security.protocol = SASL_SSL

# Identifies the SASL mechanism to use.
sasl.mechanism = AWS_MSK_IAM

# Binds SASL client implementation.
sasl.jaas.config = software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;

# Encapsulates constructing a SigV4 signature based on extracted credentials.
# The SASL client bound by "sasl.jaas.config" invokes this class.
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
```

**When I try to consume from my Databricks cluster using spark, I receive the following error:**

```
Caused by: kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.ClassCastException: software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler cannot be cast to kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.AuthenticateCallbackHandler
```

Here is my cluster config:
[image]

The libraries I'm using in the cluster:

[image]

And the code I'm running on Databricks:

```
raw = (
    spark
        .readStream
        .format('kafka')
        .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'b-.kafka.*********.***********.amazonaws.com:9098')
        .option('subscribe', 'TopicTest') 
        .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest')
        .option('kafka.sasl.mechanism', 'AWS_MSK_IAM')
        .option('kafka.security.protocol', 'SASL_SSL')
        .option('kafka.sasl.jaas.config', 'software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;')
        .option('kafka.sasl.client.callback.handler.class', 'software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler')
        .load()
)
```

Comment: I've been back-and-forth with Databricks support on this. Essentially Databricks has shaded the `org.apache.kafka.common` to `kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common` which means that this will not work out of the box. I've had to move on and use SASL/SCRAM, but in theory you could shade the iam authenticator yourself. I'm not 100% sure how.

Comment: Hi @AndrewGelnar, thanks for the reply, do you mean that as of now this won't work at all for AWS IAM? Or were you able to run AWS IAM but with SASL/SCRAM instead of SASL_SSL?

Comment: SASL/SCRAM is a different mechanism and is not integrated with IAM. MSK uses usernames/passwords configured in AWS secretsmanager https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-password.html

Comment: I am facing a similar issue did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Though I haven't tested this, based on the comment from Andrew on being theoretically able to relocate the dependency, I dug a bit into the source of aws-msk-iam-auth. They have a `compileOnly('org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.4.1')` in their `build.gradle`. Hence the uber jar doesn't contain this library and is picked up from whatever databricks has (and shaded).

They are also relocating all their dependent jars [with a prefix](https://github.com/aws/aws-msk-iam-auth/blob/main/build.gradle#L111). So changing the `compileOnly` to `implementation` and rebuilding the uber jar with `gradle clean shadowJar` should include and relocate the kafka jars without any conflicts when uploading to databricks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, I forked `aws-msk-iam-auth` in order to make it compatible with databricks. Just add the jar from the following release https://github.com/Iziwork/aws-msk-iam-auth-for-databricks/releases/tag/v1.1.2-databricks to your cluster.

Comment: Good solution but also it has drawback like maintaining seperate application

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced this issue and found the mistake in the config. Databricks uses shaded kafka libraries, that's why we should use paths to shaded libraries in the config as described [here](https://sasl.client.callback.handler.class%20=%20software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler):

```
sasl.jaas.config = shadedmskiam.software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = shadedmskiam.software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
```